# In Django how can I use string concatenation (||"-"||) for fields in a database and display them in the form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to use this `||"-"||` SQL string concatenation between `x = models.CharField(max_length=30)` and `y = models.CharField(max_length=30)`. Next in the combobox on the form, I would like to display all `x` and `y` fields of the database, like this: `x-y`

Being new to Django, I don't know how to pass the parameter in `views.py` in this line: `object_voyage = form.cleaned_data['voyage']`, considering that `'voyage'` is not a database field because there are `x` and `y` in the database. `voyage` is the name of the containment. I tried using `CharField` and `Concat`, but I don't know if it's the right solution. Maybe I've completely got the wrong approach and need a different way, I don't know.

The error is that the combobox of the form is not displayed at all. Thank you all

The SQL code, to make you understand better, would be this: `SELECT x||"-"||y FROM Table1`

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MyVoyage(models.Model): 
    x = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    y = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    other = models.CharField(max_length=30) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.other, self.x, self.y
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyVoyage
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
  
class Form_MyVoyage(forms.Form):
    voyage = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyVoyage.objects.annotate(match=Concat('x', Value('-'), 'y', output_field=CharField())))
    other = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyVoyage.objects.values_list('other', flat=True).distinct())
```

**views.py**

```
def View_MyVoyage(request):
    object_voyage = None
    object_other = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form_MyVoyage(request.POST, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object_voyage = form.cleaned_data['voyage']
            object_other = form.cleaned_data['other']
    else:
        form = Form_MyVoyage()
     
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'object_voyage': object_voyage,
        'object_other': object_other
    }
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your code a bit like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyVoyage(models.Model): 
    x = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    y = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    other = models.CharField(max_length=30) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.x}-{self.y}"
```

And the serializer:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import MyVoyage
  
class Form_MyVoyage(forms.Form):
    voyage = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyVoyage.objects.all())
    other = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyVoyage.objects.values_list('other', flat=True).distinct())
```

View:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Form_MyVoyage

def View_MyVoyage(request):
    object_voyage = None
    object_other = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form_MyVoyage(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object_voyage = form.cleaned_data['voyage']
            object_other = form.cleaned_data['other']
    else:
        form = Form_MyVoyage()
     
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'object_voyage': object_voyage,
        'object_other': object_other
    }
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)
```

Comment: @Folidexman updated the code, it should work, what is the problem now ?

Comment: Only now I realized that in my code I forgot to write one thing. Besides x and z, there is also "other". They are in the same form, they are 2 comboboxes. In one combobox is other, while in the other is x+z. I tried your code with return self.other, f"{self.x}-{self.y}", but it doesn't work. Can you review my updated code please and then edit your answer? I'll be happy to accept it, thank you

Comment: Being new to Django I ask you a question about your code: why shouldn't I write self.other in the return of def __str__(self)? Why NOT write self.other there? (and instead self.x and self.y are written). Thank you

Comment: @Folidexman you don’t have to return any object in str method, the str method is just to print some string to show details about that object

Comment: You said that the str method is just to print the string to show details about that object, ok, so you print {self.x}-{self.y}. I didn't understand one thing.

In the form I have 2 comboboxes: one for x-y, and one for "other". If with the str method I print the string to show details about this object, then I wonder: shouldn't it be the same situation for "other" too? Why shouldn't "other" show details about this item? Thank you

Comment: I accepted (and upvoted) your answer, thanks. I'm still waiting for a response to the above comment. Thank you

Comment: I noticed that maybe I can do without object_other = None, object_voyage = form.cleaned_data['voyage'] and 'object_voyage': object_voyage, . Instead you wrote it in your answer. Can you be more specific please? Are these needed or not? I await your reply, thank you